# Metodo $push no funciona (MongoDB, Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

que tal. Estoy teniendo un problema. Tengo un array en mongodb, que se supone que debe almacenar objetos, pero no puedo agregarlos.

```
Student.update(mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5bc25777d9dded06a4635430"),{$push:{sanctions:{reason:'test'}}});
```

Se supone que mongoose encuentra el documento en l;a base de datos y despues haria un push como si fuese un array normal de javascript. Pero no lo hace.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta forma:

```
Student.update(
  {_id: "5bc25777d9dded06a4635430"},
  {$push: {sanctions: {reason:'test'}}}
);
```